# Retrieve inbox notifications

Tags: support, notifications

Hi,

Is there a way to retrieve any notification that appears in the inbox of stackexchange? Or is there another technique to retrieve notifications on updates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, no.  The inbox isn't exposed (as doing so would require user authentication, which is also not yet available).

However, most of what goes into the inbox is available* via the API.  Look into `/users/{id}/questions` and `/users/{id}/mentioned`.

<sub>*Polling (very occasionally) with sort=activity/creation and min=<last time you polled>.</sub>

Comment: `However, most of what goes into the inbox is available* via the API. `So why the need for authentification. There's nothing in the inbox that can't be seen by API requests. But if you want to get the exact same result as the inbox, you'd have to do hundreds of API requests. (check each of the users question for an update)